# React JS external script Load

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm a beginner in React/Node.js and i got a problem on my custom shopify app dev.

i have to import, load and save an external js file on my current shoppify shop from the back.

In my react project, i could import the script via an init on button click as :

```
const onClick = () => {
 if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      addScript({
        src: `https://sdk.com/loader.js`,
        id: "script",
        async: "true",

        onLoad: () => {
          console.log("script initialized!");
        },
      });
    }
  };
```

But when i refresh, close and reopen, i have to re-import the script.

My question is, how can i adjust my code to save the script on my DOM.

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't add greetings or signatures to your questions. See [ask] and take the [tour]. We're not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```js
const onClick = () => {
    const exists = document.getElementById("myScript");
    if (!exists) {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "https://sdk.com/loader.js";
        script.id = "myScript";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        script.onload = () => {
            console.log("Script loaded")
        }
    }
}
```